# Installed Sahi, dashboard not starting

Tags: installation, sahi

I have just installed Sahi, which created a shortcut at my desktop. I double-clicked it, but no dashboard appeared. What is the problem?

The shortcut directs to "directory where sahi installed"\sahi\userdata\bin\start_dashboard.bat

From [this link](http://216.119.129.132.static.a2webhosting.com/forums/discussion/6191/sahi-will-not-start/p1), it suggest that there should be a x64 version of Sahi for Windows... But I seem not find it except some .zip files [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sahi/files/sahi-v44/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up downloading the java from [here](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp), installing the x64 version (as my OS is x64), and sahi dashboard worked...